# Get maven plugin property in scala class

Tags: scala, jenkins

I´ve been looking in google but I cannot find a work solution.

I´m using Maven where I´m using the plugin

> com.bazaarvoice.maven.plugins

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>com.bazaarvoice.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>process-exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>Start-Service-discovery-Mock</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>start</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>${skipStartService}</skip>
                            <name>start-service-discovery-mock</name>

                            <arguments>
                                <argument>java</argument>
                                <argument>-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError</argument>
                                <argument>-Xmx512M</argument>
                                <argument>-Xms256M</argument>
                                <argument>-Xss1M</argument>
                                <argument>-XX:+UseParallelGC</argument>
                                <argument>-cp</argument>
                                <argument>
                                   service-${project.version}.jar${path.separator}../../f2e-mock-service/target/lib/*
                                </argument>
                                <argument>mocks.bootables.MockBootable</argument>
                                <argument>-DENDPOINTS=${project.build.directory}${path.separator}classes${path.separator}service-discovery${path.separator}endpoints.conf
                                </argument>
                                <argument>-DPORT=8600</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
```

Wher eI´m settings two properties as arguments `-DENDPOINTS=bla` and `-DPORT=8600`

But from the scala class `MockBootable` that I´, invoking I cannot get those properties

```
  println("************** PROPERTIES *****************")
  sys.props.foreach(entry => {
    println(s"${entry._1} -> ${entry._2}")
  })
  val port = sys.props.getOrElse("PORT", "666").toInt
  var path = sys.props.getOrElse("ENDPOINTS", null)
```

Those always return the else value

Any idea?

**SOLUTION**

In the plugin the arguments has to be defined after the jvm arguments but before the main class

```
 <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.bazaarvoice.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>process-exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.7</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>Start-Service-discovery-Mock</id>
                            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>start</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <skip>${skipStartService}</skip>
                                <name>start-service-discovery-mock</name>

                                <arguments>
                                    <argument>java</argument>
                                    <argument>-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError</argument>
                                    <argument>-Xmx512M</argument>
                                    <argument>-Xms256M</argument>
                                    <argument>-Xss1M</argument>
                                    <argument>-XX:+UseParallelGC</argument>
                                    <argument>-cp</argument>
                                    <argument>
                                       service-${project.version}.jar${path.separator}../../f2e-mock-service/target/lib/*
                                    </argument>
                                    <argument>-DENDPOINTS=${project.build.directory}${path.separator}classes${path.separator}service-discovery${path.separator}endpoints.conf
                                    </argument>
                                    <argument>-DPORT=8600</argument>
<argument>mocks.bootables.MockBootable</argument>
                                </arguments>
                            </configuration>
```

Regards.

Comment: The property names have to be the same as the ones you passed in. So, use `sys.props.getOrElse("ENDPOINTS", "666")` instead.

Comment: It is sorry I post my question poorly. I found the solution anyway